# Display hostname in the top bar (LXPanel)

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B+. I would like to have the hostname displayed in the top bar (LXPanel), similar to a panel applet/plugin.

How can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried to write a plugin (see https://wiki.lxde.org/en/How_to_write_plugins_for_LXPanel )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to display the hostname on the lxpanel.

(#1) A simple way is to write a program to post the hostname. An example would be a python program which is in a file `$HOME/bin/dsphost1.py` with execute permisson (`chmod +x dsphost1.py`). This program will read the hostname and open a window with the hostname on an exit button (or label). This window is placed three fifths on the lxpanel (and can be placed any where on the display). If the `bin` director was just created, the `PATH` variable will need to be modified, `export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` or reboot (see .profile).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Program name is dsphost1.py

import Tkinter as tk    # For python3, use tkinter.

mywindow = tk.Tk()

fp = open("/etc/hostname", "r")
hn = fp.read().strip()
fp.close()

w = str((len(hn) + 1) * 14)
x = str(mywindow.winfo_screenwidth() / 5 * 3)
whxy = w + "x36+" + x + "+1"    # wh = width/height, xy = coordinates
mywindow.geometry(whxy)
tk.Button(text = hn, font=("Courier", 18), command=quit).pack()
#tk.Label(text = hn, font=("Courier", 18)).pack()
mywindow.overrideredirect(1)
mywindow.mainloop()
```

To test type `dsphost1.py &` and to stop, click on the button or use the `kill ...` command with pid provided for the background process. Adjust width, height and coordinates for your needs. To run the program on reboot/boot, append `@dsphost1.py` to the end of `$HOME/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` file.

(#2) Same as #1 using label with known hostname at different coordinates.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Program name is dsphost2.py

import Tkinter as tk

mywindow = tk.Tk()
mywindow.geometry("50x16+0+36")
tk.Label(text="RPi4", font=("Arial 14 bold")).pack()    #works better
#tk.Label(text="RPi4", font=("Arial Bold", 14)).pack()
mywindow.overrideredirect(1)
mywindow.mainloop()
```

(#3) The default panel (`$HOME/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel`) has three sections. The left is menu/launch, center is running window programs selection/iconification and right is task/applets. Another way to use the panel is to open a window program.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Program name is dsphost3.py.

import Tkinter as tk

mywindow = tk.Tk()

fp = open('/etc/hostname', 'r')
hn = fp.read().strip()
fp.close()

img = tk.PhotoImage(file = '/usr/share/lxpanel/images/my-computer.png')
mywindow.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', mywindow._w, img)

mywindow.title(hn)
mywindow.geometry('-2+36')
#mywindow.geometry('1x1-1-1')    # For hidden window.
tk.Button(text = hn, font=('Courier', 18), command=quit).pack()
#label = tk.Label(mywindow, text = hn, font=('Courier', 18)).pack()
mywindow.mainloop()
```

(#4) The lxpanel has a GUI to add and delete items that are predefined (right click on the panel). Sometimes it is easier to make your own. Three things are needed to create a launch button, a program to launch, a `.desktop` file, and configuration in the `panel` file. First, the program in `$HOME/bin/dsphost4.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Program name is dsphost4.py.

import Tkinter as tk

def exit():
    quit()

mywindow = tk.Tk()

mywindow.title('RPi4')
x = str(mywindow.winfo_screenwidth() / 4)
mywindow.geometry('+' + x + '+36')
tk.Button(text = 'RPi4', font=('Courier', 18), command=quit).pack()
mywindow.overrideredirect(1)
mywindow.after(5000, exit)
mywindow.mainloop()
```

Second, the `.desktop` file in `$HOME/.local/share/applications/PiHost4.desktop`. If mouse pointer on icon, the Name will hover. If you have access to make a .png or .ico (like Windows Paint), a 64x64 pixel or less can be used for `Icon=/home/pi/.local/share/your_icon.ico` (full path required - `$HOME` will not work).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=RPi4
TryExec=dsphost4.py
Exec=dsphost4.py
Icon=my-computer
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility
StartupNotify=true
```

Third, modify the `$HOME/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel` file, by adding the `PiHost4.desktop` stanza at the end of the `lanuchbar` stanza. There may be two different kind of stanza.

```
Plugin {
  type=launchbar
  Config {
    Button {
      id=lxde-x-www-browser.desktop
    }
    Button {
      id=pcmanfm.desktop
    }
    ...
    Button {
      id=PiHost4.desktop
    }
  ...
```

OR

```
Plugin {
  type=launchbar
  Config {
    Button {
      id=chromium-browser.desktop
    }
  }
}
 ...
Plugin {
  type=launchbar
  Config {
    Button {
      id=PiHost4.desktop
    }
  }
}
```

The command `lxpanelctl restart` will use the new changes to the panel. Use a different directory to back up the `panel` as multiple files here are multiple panels.

EDIT: On Python 2.7 with TKinter the format of `font=("Times 14 bold")` works better than the orginal post.

[image: Screenshot with all four options]

Answer (score 1):

I have wanted to do something similar, but can find no existing code, so I decided to write a LXpanel plugin

[image]

```
#include <lxpanel/plugin.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#define LabelSize 32

GtkWidget *test_constructor(LXPanel *panel, config_setting_t *settings)
{
 /* panel is a pointer to the panel and
     settings is a pointer to the configuration data
     since we don't use it, we'll make sure it doesn't
     give us an error at compilation time */
 (void)panel;
 (void)settings;

 // make a label out of the hostname
 char cIdBuf[LabelSize+1] = {'\0'};
 FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen("/etc/hostname", "r");
 fgets(cIdBuf, LabelSize, fp);
 fclose(fp);

 // create a label widget instance
 GtkWidget *pLabel = gtk_label_new(cIdBuf);

 // set the label to be visible
 gtk_widget_show(pLabel);

 // need to create a container to be able to set a border
 GtkWidget *p = gtk_event_box_new();

 // our widget doesn't have a window...
 // it is usually illegal to call gtk_widget_set_has_window() from application but for GtkEventBox it doesn't hurt
 gtk_widget_set_has_window(p, FALSE);

 // set border width
 gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(p), 1);

 // add the label to the container
 gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(p), pLabel);

 // set the size we want
 // gtk_widget_set_size_request(p, 100, 25);

 // success!!!
 return p;
}

FM_DEFINE_MODULE(lxpanel_gtk, test)

/* Plugin descriptor. */
LXPanelPluginInit fm_module_init_lxpanel_gtk = {
   .name = "HostnamePlugin",
   .description = "Display Hostname",
   .one_per_system = 1,

   // assigning our functions to provided pointers.
   .new_instance = test_constructor
};
```

---

To compile from source

```
sudo apt install lxpanel-dev  
gcc -Wall `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 lxpanel` -shared -fPIC hostname.c -o hostname.so `pkg-config --libs lxpanel`
```

For *Raspberry Pi OS-Bullseye* (with GTK3)

```
gcc -Wall `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 lxpanel` -shared -fPIC hostname.c -o hostname.so `pkg-config --libs lxpanel`
```

The source and compiled versions `Raspberry Pi OS-Buster` (GTK2 or earlier) `Raspberry Pi OS-Bullseye` 32 or 64 bit can be downloaded  [Hostname](http://binnie.id.au/Downloads/hostname.tgz)

Answer (score 0):

@Milliways
Hi is it also possible to show the current IP from the Raspberry (Bullseye 32-bit)? I saw a file called get_ip.c in your source
Thanks