# Display IP Address on LXPanel

Tags: display, lxde, plugins

I'd like to print on the LXDE Pannel (LXPanel) the IP address of my Raspberry Pi, so I can have a direct view about how to connect to the Pi from another computer when I reboot it, since its IP is defined dynamically and I have no keyboard nor mouse connected to the Pi

I'd like something like this :

[image]

I'm looking for a solution to print the output of a command, like in MATE, where a "command Applet" allows to print a command like :

```
ifconfig | grep inet | head -n 1 |  awk '{print $2}'
```

Some one has an idea to do the same for LXDE ?

Comment: you could query the router to see the IP that was given to the RPi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a plugin which displays the hostname, which could be adapted. http://binnie.id.au/Downloads/hostname.tgz

You don't actually need to know the IP address `hostname.local` works in most circumstances.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92797/8697

`hostname -I` will return the IP address as a string.

If you replace the 2 lines in the source

```
fp = fopen("/etc/hostname", "r");
fgets(cIdBuf, LabelSize, fp);
```

with the following

```
fp = popen("hostname -I","r");  // Setup our pipe for reading and execute our command.
if(fp)  fgets(cIdBuf, LabelSize , fp);  // Get the data from the process execution
```

it will display IP.

I probably should make this a config option

Comment: Works perfectly fine, thanks! Indeed, a customizable command as a config option would be even better