# Get metainformation at boot-screen

Tags: boot, display, pi-4

I asked myself if there is a possibility to get metainformation of the raspberry Pi (like IP4 Adress, MAC Adress etc.) displayed on booting process. Maybe extended with a timeout to read the Information.

With this information it would be easy and fast to identify a Pi.

Would be great If someone had an advice where to make these settings.

I am using a RPI4 with Raspbian 2020-02-13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a trivial exercise to display information about the Pi.
See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/85016/8697

You could arrange to run these on boot if you wish - but I see no need to inflict this on the rest of the world.

I don't bother with MAC - but this is also possible (if you can find a reason which would make it useful).

I display the `hostname` on the taskbar when I boot to GUI - because it makes it clear which of my many Pi is currently connected to my monitor. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92797/8697