# Display permanent label text in Raspberry Pi Task Bar

Tags: gui, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, lxde, taskbar, lxpanel

Referring to the `Task Bar` of pi's GUI (not the top of open application windows but the screen's task bar), I would like to display a permanent text label so I know which of many boot disks I'm using.

My task bar currently contains application icons on the left, and clock, connections, and audio icons on the right. I know how to add and delete items from the options but am wondering if there is a way to display a text label in the task bar.

I found the same question on another forum https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1326603#p1326603 but no useful answer there and the topic is now locked.

I have a laborious alternative where I manually edit an image to add the label and use the image as desktop wallpaper but it is often hidden by open windows and I would prefer it to be in the task bar.

Any ideas of how to achieve this gratefully received (pi400, Raspberry Pi OS 32 bit).

**update**

After some exploration I have found a config file here:

```
~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel
```

That begins:

```
# lxpanel <profile> config file. Manually editing is not recommended.
# Use preference dialog in lxpanel to adjust config when you can.
```

and contains an entry that might be where I could add something:

```
Plugin {
  type=taskbar
  expand=1
  Config {
    tooltips=1
    IconsOnly=0
    ShowAllDesks=0
    UseMouseWheel=1
    UseUrgencyHint=1
    FlatButton=0
    MaxTaskWidth=200
    spacing=1
    GroupedTasks=0
  }
}
```

Has anyone edited this file or knows what properties are available for setting?

Comment: This is not specifically about Raspberry Pi but LXDE

Comment: @MatsK I've added the lxde tag, I'm open to any method, such as some setting I don't know about.

Comment: this is a Linux related question ... it belongs at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no existing code to "display a permanent text label" although you can kludge by just changing the name of an existing plugin.

I have written [a plugin to display hostname](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92797/8697) and it would be simple to modify to display an arbitrary string.

Comment: thanks, that looks to be just the thing. I will have a play with it later and report back.